# JIRA resolution unexpectedly set to "Fixed" whenever I update the ticket

Tags: jira

I've built a custom workflow for my development process and use a transition post-message to set the Resolution to "Fixed" at the end of my workflow. I've been careful to ensure that I only use that transition at the end of the workflow.

However, whenever I edit my ticket (modifying *any* field) using the editor modal (pushing the "E" key"), the resolution changes to "Fixed". This behavior is unexpected and incorrect for my workflow.

When I edit a ticket directly without the modal (i.e. clicking in to the field), this behavior does *not* happen - the resolution remains unchanged.

Ideas on what's going on?

[image: Transition state]

Comment: How is your postfunction? wich plugin provides it?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question? I don't use a plugin - just the native workflow builder. Attaching a screenshot for reference.

Comment: It may be set on screen. Did you read this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/212059/editing-an-issue-changes-it-to-fixed-how-do-i-stop-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert, in the comments above, directed me to an Atlassian Support link that answered the question.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/212059/editing-an-issue-changes-it-to-fixed-how-do-i-stop-this

> If resolution is placed on an a screen and the screen is used for any
>   update (create, edit or transition), then the resolution will be set
>   to something.

I had the "resolution" field on my edit screen.